# Need suggestions to handle view updates

Tags: ractivejs

In an application currently I am loading my views using routers like below

```
  router('menu/:item', function (item) {
     app.uiHandler.toggleMenuSelected('menu', item);
     // The below method updates the view with selected menu item's model.
         app.channel.publish('menu', item);
  });
```

Currently each menu item shares same data object. But the master view is replaced with new html based on each menu selection.

I am thinking to have instance like below for each menu item

```
 var ractive = new Ractive({
      el: 'container', // el is same for all instances.
      template: '<p> I am {{selection}}, after {{prevSelection}}!</p>',
      data: { selection: 'Home', prevSelection: 'Profile' }
 });
```

But here my doubt is as I will be invoking each instance to render the view into 'container' whenever hash is changed how to clear all the two way data bindings created when master view is replaced with new html. Please help me on this.

If I am handling in wrong way, what would be the best way to handle the same.

Note : My question might sound like stupid, but I am looking for clarification on this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to clear all the two way data bindings created when master view is replaced with new html

You can use `teardown()` to destroy the ractive instance, but if you don't ractive will do that automatically as soon as you try to render a new instance into the same container.

That said, it's probably better to have one instance and only update the data. I.e. when the section changes call `ractive.set({ selection: 'Profile', prevSelection: 'Home' })`.